# CSS Hover - Change Title, Description and Background when hovering over block

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS items that I am trying to simultaneously change the hover effect for when rolling over .blocks-item

.blocks-item
.blocks-item-title
.blocks-item-description
.blocks-item-link

I have set .blocks-item:hover to the following:

```
.blocks-item:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #15191f;
}
```

If I do the following:

```
.blocks-item:hover,
.blocks-item-title:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #15191f;
}
```

Then the title only changes colour when rolled over with the mouse which I am expecting.

I am trying to bind all of the 4 elements so that I only need to hover over .blocks-item to be able to change the hover effect of all of the other items (description, title, link)

What is the best way of going about this?
I know this has been answered many times but struggling to adapt the solutions.
Appreciate the understanding and help

HTML:

```
<ul class="blocks-list">
    <li class="blocks-item">
        <a href="/support/tickets/new" class="blocks-item-link">
            <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-pencil"></span></span>
            <span class="blocks-item-title">Create Ticket</span>
            <span class="blocks-item-description">Submit a tracked ticket for any IT queries or issues here</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="blocks-item">
        <a href="tel:" class="blocks-item-link">
            <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-phone-handset"></span></span>
            <span class="blocks-item-title">Call Us</span>
            <span class="blocks-item-description">Our call centre is available 24/7 to help with issues and queries</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="blocks-item">
        <a href="#!" onclick="window.fcWidget.open();" class="blocks-item-link">
            <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-bubble"></span></span>
            <span class="blocks-item-title">Live Chat</span>
            <span class="blocks-item-description">Our live chat service is available from 8am - 8pm Monday - Friday</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="blocks-item">
        <a href="mailto:?subject=Support Request - " class="blocks-item-link">
            <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-envelope"></span></span>
            <span class="blocks-item-title">Email</span>
            <span class="blocks-item-description">For non-urgent issues, queries or general enquiries. We will respond within 24 Hours</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Assuming the block-item-title etc are children of blocks-item, then `.blocks-item:hover .blocks-item-title { color: red }`

Comment: What is the structure of your html?

Comment: Thanks for this, Dont think I have made them children as it doesnt quite work -_- back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Added HTML to original Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are children of `.blocks-item`, it's pretty simple.  Start with a CSS selector `.blocks-item:hover` and then use a selector to target what you want to change.

```css
.blocks-item:hover .blocks-item-title {
  color: red
}

.blocks-item:hover .blocks-item-description {
  color: green
}

.blocks-item:hover .blocks-item-link {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="blocks-list">
  <li class="blocks-item">
    <a href="/support/tickets/new" class="blocks-item-link">
      <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-pencil"></span></span>
      <span class="blocks-item-title">Create Ticket</span>
      <span class="blocks-item-description">Submit a tracked ticket for any IT queries or issues here</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="blocks-item">
    <a href="tel:" class="blocks-item-link">
      <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-phone-handset"></span></span>
      <span class="blocks-item-title">Call Us</span>
      <span class="blocks-item-description">Our call centre is available 24/7 to help with issues and queries</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="blocks-item">
    <a href="#!" onclick="window.fcWidget.open();" class="blocks-item-link">
      <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-bubble"></span></span>
      <span class="blocks-item-title">Live Chat</span>
      <span class="blocks-item-description">Our live chat service is available from 8am - 8pm Monday - Friday</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="blocks-item">
    <a href="mailto:?subject=Support Request - " class="blocks-item-link">
      <span class="block-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-envelope"></span></span>
      <span class="blocks-item-title">Email</span>
      <span class="blocks-item-description">For non-urgent issues, queries or general enquiries. We will respond within 24 Hours</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. Works perfectly. From my understanding of this, what you've done is referenced each subclass for .block-item but i have to do it for each item as I haven't parented them correctly?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with each.  If you just want to say change color and you have no other styles on the child items, then just set the style on the hovered .blocks-item.